# Java split string to get only two words

Tags: java, string, split, substring, contains

I have a Java string like "hello world bye moon" and I'm looking for an efficient way to extract the first two words from it. Currently, I'm using the split method and then concatenating the first two elements of the resulting array. However, I'm wondering if there's a more concise and efficient way to achieve this.

Here's my current code:

```
public class ExtractFirstTwoWords {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String inputString = "hello world bye moon";

        // Split the string into words
        String[] words = inputString.split(" ");

        // Check if there are at least two words
        if (words.length >= 2) {
            // Extract the first two words
            String firstTwoWords = words[0] + " " + words[1];
            System.out.println("First two words: " + firstTwoWords);
        } else {
            System.out.println("The input string does not contain at least two words.");
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a built-in Java method or a more efficient approach to extract the first two words from a string without splitting and concatenating all the words in the string?

Comment: Why is this not short and efficient?

Comment: alternatively get the index of the second whitespace and take a substring until that second index.

Comment: But it is equally long and inefficient

Comment: f1sh Because you can't reuse the code and it needs unnecessary variables. And arrays are never perfect anyway

Comment: String splitting or taking a substring are probably the two most efficient ways to do this.  For kicks, I gave a regex answer which st least is easy on the eyes.

Comment: @bschle To be fair your code is perfectly fine, once you move the declarations where they're needed instead of the beginning of code block. It's readable and what it does is perfectly clear. It's not inefficient and it's short and to the point.

Comment: @Federico klez Culloca
Thanks but you always have to add + " " + newStringArray[x] if you want longer and so it is not perfect with a long sat

Comment: @bschle of course you can reuse this code, move it to a method. And the variables can be inlined. You're splitting hairs here.

Comment: Yeah, i know thanks but i must use witch my opinion an very long array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, you can achieve this more efficiently and concisely without splitting and concatenating by using the `StringTokenizer` class or regular expressions. Here's an example using `StringTokenizer`:

```java
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class ExtractFirstTwoWords {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String inputString = "hello world bye moon";

        // Use StringTokenizer to split the string into words
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(inputString);

        // Check if there are at least two words
        if (tokenizer.countTokens() >= 2) {
            // Extract the first two words
            String firstTwoWords = tokenizer.nextToken() + " " + tokenizer.nextToken();
            System.out.println("First two words: " + firstTwoWords);
        } else {
            System.out.println("The input string does not contain at least two words.");
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use regular expressions for a more powerful and flexible approach:

```java
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class ExtractFirstTwoWords {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String inputString = "hello world bye moon";

        // Define a regular expression to match words
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b\\w+\\b");

        // Create a Matcher
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputString);

        // Find the first two words
        StringBuilder firstTwoWords = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < 2 && matcher.find(); i++) {
            firstTwoWords.append(matcher.group()).append(" ");
        }

        if (firstTwoWords.length() > 0) {
            // Remove the trailing space
            firstTwoWords.setLength(firstTwoWords.length() - 1);
            System.out.println("First two words: " + firstTwoWords.toString());
        } else {
            System.out.println("The input string does not contain at least two words.");
        }
    }
}
```

Both of these approaches avoid creating an intermediate array and are more efficient for extracting the first two words from a string.

Comment: public static String extractSubstring(String inputString, int startWordIndex, int length) {
    String[] words = inputString.split(" ");
    StringBuilder extractedSubstring = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = startWordIndex; i < startWordIndex + length && i < words.length; i++) {
        extractedSubstring.append(words[i]).append(" ");
    }

    return extractedSubstring.toString().trim();
}

Answer (score 2):

You can also use substring:

```
 String string = "hello world bye moon";
 String stringTwo = string.substring(0, string.indexOf(' ', string.indexOf(' ')+1));
 
 System.out.println(stringTwo);
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to `String#split()`, you could use a regex replacement approach:

```java
String string = "hello world bye moon";
String firstTwo = string.replaceAll("(\\w+ \\w+).*", "$1");
System.out.println(firstTwo);  // hello world
```

Comment: Just small notice: the `.*` will require from regex to traverse entire line, not just first two words.

Comment: @Pshemo ... but `.*` won't match across lines, and also the goal is to just extract the first 2 words, and so we match the remainder of the string to access the capture group.

Comment: "*`.*` won't match across lines*" true since by default `.` doesn't match line separators. Just wanted to point out that this solution will still require to iterate over that line which may be noticeable when working with string with long first/only line. For *such cases* better solution would be using combination of `indexOf`/`substring`, or `Matcher#find` with regex like `\\w+ \\w+`, or even calling `Scanner#next` twice and concatenate results. BUT if first line is not that long (like in OP example) your solution should also be fine.

Comment: This is short, but I doubt its efficient. Under the hood the regex needs to be compiled before it is used.

Comment: @Willempie I already gave this caveat under the OP.  Your comment is not needed here.  Sometimes maximum performance is what matters most, and other times readability/maintainability is more important.

Comment: This solution is slower due to hidden complexity.  As someone already stated, regular expression is compiled to state machine and then used to match the input.  Regular expression is great for matching complex patterns in large string but would not be good for simple solution where a loop will out perform it.  Here's a simple comparison of a loop and regular expression.  https://onlinegdb.com/-P30VnzDL

Answer (score 0):

The fast solution is one that doesn't process the entire string.  Imagine if the string is thousands of characters long with a lot of white spaces.  It should read just enough characters to get the first two words.  You can use String.indexOf to get the second space.  Or you could write your own as below:

```
public class Main{
   static String firstTwoWords(String s){
      int spaces = 0;
      int i = 0;
      for(i=0; i<s.length() && spaces < 2; i++)
         if (s.charAt(i) == ' ') 
            spaces++;
      return s.substring(0, i);
   }
   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s0 = "hello";
        String s1 = "hello world";
        String s2 = "hello world peple";
        System.out.println(firstTwoWords(s0));
        System.out.println(firstTwoWords(s1));
        System.out.println(firstTwoWords(s2));
    }
}
```

Comment: I would imagine this is and the one that uses indexOf are the two fastest one.  The most expensive operation is the substring as it has to make a copy of the first two words.  That requires additional memory.

Comment: At this point you should generalize it to `n` words by passing it as a parameter and checking `spaces` against that. (I know that's not in the body of the original post, but it's hinted at in the comments)

Comment: But if you want it for big sentences it would be good to add this. ` static String firstTwoWords(String s, int amount){
        int spaces = 0;
        int i = 0;
        for(i=0; i<s.length() && spaces < amount; i++)
            if (s.charAt(i) == ' ')
                spaces++;
        return s.substring(0, i);
    }`

Comment: Yes, but I assume you only want at most the first two words.  But yes, you can make it general to deal with any number of words.

Comment: Yes, you're right that I only wanted to wei. But so you can better reuse in the future

Answer (score -1):

Reading your comments it seems that you actually want a method that, given a string and a number `n`, extracts the first `n` words from said string.

Here's a quick and dirty version using streams.

```
public static String extractWords(String s, int howMany) {
    var splitString = s.split(" ");
    // TODO: make sure `howMany` is not too big
    return java.util.Arrays.stream(splitString)  // create stream
                           .limit(howMany)       // take only `howMany` elements
                           .collect(java.util.stream.Collectors.joining(" ")); // re-join with spaces
}
```

And a version with sub-arrays

```
public static String extractWords(String s, int howMany) {
    var splitString = s.split(" ");
    // TODO: make sure `howMany` is not too big
    var subArray = java.util.Arrays.copyOf(splitString, howMany); // extract sub array
    return String.join(" ", subArray);                            // return joined strings
}
```

In both versions checking the parameters are valid (i.e. string is not null and there are enough words to return) is left as an exercise for the reader

Comment: Why you mean an dirty version? But thanks

Comment: I mean it doesn't check its inputs

Comment: This version would split the entire string.  If the string is really long with a lot of white spaces, it would traverse the entire string, creating substring for each word and putting them into an array.  This is not a fast solution and it consumes more memory.

Comment: @Cheng Thao your right to long sentences is this and my option is not good.